# unable to install production app from appexchange

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, package-install

We have our application published in Appexchange. However, if we click on **Test Drive** or **Get it Now** I am getting "Hmm. Something's not right.Try refreshing the page, or come back to AppExchange in a few minutes." error after filling up all the details. I don't know how to approach to this issue. I see that there are some known issues on this scenario however, that is just a workaround. See this link [Here.](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000nvoBQAQ&title=hmm-something-s-not-right-error-after-click-get-it-now-and-install-in-production) It says just nothing but the managed package *installation URL*. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this issue on appexchange so that customers can directly click on Get it Now and be able to use application. Below is the image that is showing after the process. 
 [image]

Thank you.